# Facebook Android App Warning - URL Compliance

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I got a warning alert with a fix now badge and it says on dashboard "We've restricted this app for violating the Facebook Platform Policies". The alert says this

URL(s) listed on your app dashboard settings could not be accessed for platform compliance review. Kindly make sure that the following field(s) on your app dashboard are working correctly:
Android: Google Package Name

The android package name of the app which is entered in the facebook settings has not yet been released on the play store and is still under dev. I am using the Login and Analytics App. How can I fix this without releasing the app?